# jquery sorting is not working for the column with value $-symbol

Tags: jquery

i am having the table with column sorting option 
below link having the code

https://jsfiddle.net/9mobgu8h/12/

i tried with this below code but not get solution, sorting done but not in the proper order
    str1 = str1.replace("$", "");
    str2 = str2.replace("$", "");

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"non-empty-string-asc": function(str1, str2) {
    str1 = str1.replace("$", "");
    str2 = str2.replace("$", "");
    if ( str1 == null || str1 == "" || str1 == 0)
        return 1;
    if ( str2 == null || str2 == "" || str2 == 0)
        return -1;
    return ((parseInt(str1) < parseInt(str2)) ? -1 : ((parseInt(str1) > parseInt(str2)) ? 1 : 0));
},

"non-empty-string-desc": function(str1, str2) {
    str1 = str1.replace("$", "");
    str2 = str2.replace("$", "");
    console.log
    if ( str1 == null || str1 == "" || str1 == 0)
        return 1;
    if ( str2 == null || str2 == "" || str2 == 0)
        return -1;
    return ((parseInt(str1) < parseInt(str2)) ? 1 : ((parseInt(str1) > parseInt(str2)) ? -1 : 0));
}
});
```

2nd column having values with $-symbol this column sorting is not in the proper order of asc, desc please help me any one to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if they are numeric or not then if they are you can convert them to number before sorting

```
str1 = str1.replace("$", ""); 
str2 = str2.replace("$", "");
if (!isNaN(str1) && !isNaN(str1)) {
   str1 = Number(str1);
   str2 = Number(str2);
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9mobgu8h/15/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    str1 = str1.replace('$','').replace(/,/g,'');
    str2 = str2.replace('$','').replace(/,/g,'');
```

With help of above code sorting is working fine for asc, desc